# On back key pressed application should go to the specified Activity? What to do help please?

Tags: android

I have a splash `Activity` which ends itself after 1 second.
Then `MainActivity` starts.

In that I have 3 image buttons: Trade, Realtors and Logistic.
After clicking on any one of them the app should go into the corresponding Activity.
Everything works until this point.

But when I click back then the Application is closing itself.
I don't want this to happen.

I want the app to go back to my MainActivity when I click the back button.

I have used `onStop();` in `SplashActivity` to end it.

Comment: Please post code how  you start the Activities and how you declared them in the manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override onBackPressed in a way like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

EDIT:

You probably finish your `MainActivity` after clicking and starting one of the following activities. You don't want to do this. Android will handle this on itself.

Also calling `onStop()` in your SplashActivity can be replaced by calling `finish()` after the desired time.

Answer (score 2):

Use this-Hope this helps

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        finish();//finish current activity 
       //do ur task to start specified activity
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Erm, is this an android answer?

Comment: yes its android answer

Comment: From android docs: "Object used to report key and button events". I never knew that buttons and keys were combined like this.

Comment: we can check for every key pressed in android also.glad that my answer helps you to know new thing buddy

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
        {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(Currentclass.this, DestinationClass.class));

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```